# Not entirely sure how my two CBVs should inherit from a base

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have realized that I've got two CBV's with 99% identical code, so I figured I'd abstract it and use a mixin where I can put all the "generic" code. The only real difference between the views are the templates they are rendering. I'm having a hard time figuring out what should be put in what class. Here's the original two CBV's

`Class 1`

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class TimesheetEditorView(View):
    form_class = TimesheetModelFormSet


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        year = kwargs.get("year") or datetime.datetime.now().year
        week = kwargs.get("week") or Week.thisweek().week
        user = request.user
        if invalid_week(week, year):
            raise Http404("Invalid week / year")

        next_year, next_week = calc_next(year, week)
        previous_year, previous_week = calc_previous(year, week)


        timesheet = Timesheet.objects.filter(year=year, week=week, user=user).order_by("project_id")  # only show timesheet rows that belongs to logged in user

        timesheet_formset = self.form_class(queryset=timesheet)
        create_timesheet_form = TimesheetModelForm(user)
        context = {
            "create_timesheet_form": create_timesheet_form,
            "timesheet_formset": timesheet_formset,
            "week": week,
            "year": year,
            "next_week": next_week,
            "next_year": next_year,
            "previous_week": previous_week,
            "previous_year": previous_year,
        }

        return render(request, "timesheets/timesheet.html", context)
```

`Class 2`

```
class TimesheetApproveView(TimesheetEditorView, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        year = kwargs.get("year") or datetime.datetime.now().year
        week = kwargs.get("week") or Week.thisweek().week
        next_year, next_week = calc_next(year, week)
        previous_year, previous_week = calc_previous(year, week)
        timesheets = Timesheet.objects.timesheets_to_approve(request.user).filter(year=year, week=week)
        context = {
            "timesheets": timesheets, 
            "year": year, 
            "week": week, 
            "next_week": next_week,
            "next_year": next_year,
            "previous_week": previous_week,
            "previous_year": previous_year,
        }

        return render(request, "timesheets/approve_timesheets.html", context)
```

I'm simply just inheriting `TimesheetEditorView` into my second class. 
As you can see, the only difference here is the templates being rendered in the `return` statement.

So, I figured I'd put that chunk of code in a base mixin:

```
class BaseTimesheet(object):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BaseTimesheet, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        year = kwargs.get("year") or datetime.datetime.now().year
        week = kwargs.get("week") or Week.thisweek().week

        next_year, next_week = calc_next(year, week)
        previous_year, previous_week = calc_previous(year, week)

        if invalid_week(week, year):
            raise Http404("Invalid week / year")

        context["week"] = week
        context["year"] = year
        context["next_week"] = next_week
        context["previous_week"] = previous_week
        context["next_year"] = next_year
        context["previous_year"] = previous_year
```

Is this the "correct" way to do it? If so - how can I makes sure that I get the `context` for each `return` statement in my two `View` classes?

E.g

```
class TimesheetApproveView(BaseTimesheet, View):
    template_name = "timesheets/approve_timesheets.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, "timesheets/timesheet.html") # how to get context?
```

`approve_timesheets.html`:

```
{% extends "base_layout.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}




<section class="mb-3">
    <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
        <div class="d-flex">


            <h5>Timesheet approvals</h5>
            <div class="ml-auto py-2">
                <a uk-icon="icon: chevron-left; ratio: 1.2"
                    href="{% url 'timesheets:approve-week' previous_year previous_week %}" role="button">
                </a>
                <a class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-small"
                    href="{% url 'timesheets:default-approve-week' %}" role="button">
                    <span>Current week</span>
                </a>

                <a uk-icon="icon: chevron-right; ratio: 1.2"
                    href="{% url 'timesheets:approve-week' next_year next_week %}" role="button">
                </a>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>



{% regroup timesheets by project as projects %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-8 offset-xl-2 col-lg-10 offset-lg-1 ">
        <form method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="table-responsive-sm">
                {% for project in projects %}
                <table class="table approve-timesheet-table">
                    <thead class="thead-light">
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{project.grouper}}</th>
                            <th>Mon</th>
                            <th>Tue</th>
                            <th>Wed</th>
                            <th>Thu</th>
                            <th>Fri</th>
                            <th>Sat</th>
                            <th>Sun</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        {% for user in project.list %}
                          ...
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                {% empty %}
                <p>No timesheets to approve for this week</p>
                <hr>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>



        </form>
    </div>
</div>






{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you forgot to *return* the `context`:

```
class BaseTimesheet:

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        year = kwargs.get("year") or datetime.datetime.now().year
        week = kwargs.get("week") or Week.thisweek().week

        next_year, next_week = calc_next(year, week)
        previous_year, previous_week = calc_previous(year, week)

        if invalid_week(week, year):
            raise Http404("Invalid week / year")

        context["week"] = week
        context["year"] = year
        context["next_week"] = next_week
        context["previous_week"] = previous_week
        context["next_year"] = next_year
        context["previous_year"] = previous_year
        return context
```

You *call* the function:

```
class TimesheetApproveView(BaseTimesheet, View):
    template_name = "timesheets/approve_timesheets.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, "timesheets/timesheet.html", self.get_context_data(**kwargs))
```

But this will error, since there is no `super().get_context_data` for a generic view. You can make use of a [**`TemplateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview), in that case you do *not* even need to specify the `get` method:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

class TimesheetApproveView(BaseTimesheet, TemplateView):
    template_name = "timesheets/approve_timesheets.html"
```

In your other view, you can then add the logic for the form:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class TimesheetEditorView(LoginRequiredMixin, BaseTimesheet, TemplateView):
    form_class = TimesheetModelFormSet
    template_name = "timesheets/timesheet.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        timesheet = Timesheet.objects.filter(
            year=context['year'],
            week=context['week'],
            user=self.request.user
        ).order_by("project_id")
        timesheet_formset = self.form_class(queryset=timesheet)
        create_timesheet_form = TimesheetModelForm(user)
        context.update(
            create_timesheet_form=create_timesheet_form,
            timesheet_formset=timesheet_formset
        )
        return context
```

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
>   [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: I just get the url pattern errors when using TemplateView
`Reverse for 'approve-week' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['timesheets/approve/(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<week>[0-9]+)/$']`

(Because I got <int:id>'s in my URL

Comment: @erikvm: no, it means you used a `{% url ... %}` but with `year` or `week` not in the context with which you render this.

Comment: @erikvm: can you edit the question, and add relevant parts of the template(s)?

Comment: Updated. Didn't add the `year` and `week` because I assume it'd be taken care of by the base Object with `context["week"] = week` and `context["year"] = year`

Comment: @erikvm: normally yes, but you forgot to return the `context` in your mixin.

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right - totally forgot to just return them. Rookie mistake! So, if I were to wanna add `post` requests to `TemplateView` - should I still inherit from `TemplateView` in the `TimesheetApproveView` class?

Comment: @erikvm: yes. Normally the `TemplateView`, will call `get_context_data` itself.

Comment: Not sure I follow? `TemplateView` calls `get_context_data`, but what about making `post` requests on `TimesheetApproveView`?

Can I just add a `def post() ...`?

Comment: @erikvm: yes, a `TemplateView` itself does not handle that, but you can `def post`, `def put`, `def patch`, etc. to handle POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, ... requests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214188/discussion-between-erikvm-and-willem-van-onsem).